# After Insert data macro not running

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-data-macro

I have a table `tblEmp` with a `After Insert` data macro defined. However, the event is not working. what I am missing here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does 'not working' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? The query syntax looks good. I've never used Data Macros. Will the AfterInsert event trigger when record is added by action query as opposed to manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move your logic to the `BeforeChange` trigger which is the state before any record (new or existing) is saved. Your logic attempts to change field values in `AfterInsert` which is after the save mode. Also, be sure to not include the table identifier, *tblEmp*, in referencing column name in macro:

[image: Data Macro Design View]

In fact, had you clicked the *Application Errors* on status bar in lower right after your current attempt, the outputted system table indicates the issue since you are in read-only mode after inserting:

> EditRecord failed because the default alias represents a record which
>   is read only.